# Custom Rewrite for Profiles

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, users

I'm currently trying to modify my rewrites to allow for an additional URL segment e.g. http://example.com/vendors/username/ by default WP allows for additional numeric segments but everything else returns a 404 error. e.g. http://example.com/vendors/test. I'm curious as how I would go about allowing URL's like these.

My current structure is: http://example.com/vendors/?username=example
It should be: http://example.com/vendors/username AND/OR http://example.com/username

But it still has to serve the original page: http://example.com/vendors/username/

I've previously examined this article, but still couldn't sort it out: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/

Comment: what is vendors, a page? add the code you have tried to your question.

Comment: Yes, Vendors is a page. I haven't tried anything, I can't seem to wrap my mind around the rewrites